# How to bind array of empty string inputs to ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind an array of empty strings to ngModel in ngFor.

```
testObject.dynamicFields = ['','','',''];
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="testLabels.length > 0">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of testObject.dynamicFields; let i = index">
      <input
        *ngIf="testLabels[i]?.type === 'text'"
        [name]="'item_' + i"
        [(ngModel)]="(testObject?.dynamicFields)[i]"
      >
      <kendo-datetimepicker
        class="form-control m-b-20"
        [name]="'item_' + i"
        *ngIf="filterLabels[i]?.dataType === 'date'"
        [format]="'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'"
        [(ngModel)]="(testObject?.dynamicFields)[i]"
      ></kendo-datetimepicker>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know where I'm doing wrong, when I enter a value in one textbox it is entering value in second textbox as well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'second textbox'?
I only see one input and a datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to highlight why this happens:

> I don't know where I'm doing wrong, when I enter a value in one textbox it is entering value in second textbox as well.

That's because both inputs are binded to the same `item` from `dynamicFields`.

Small steps:
The iteration is through the collection of `dynamicFields`.
The `item` (from `*ngFor="let item of testObject.dynamicFields`) represents a `dynamicField`. If that`dinamicField` would be an object with multiple properties (fields), then you could bind each input to a property, and they would update independently the model behind, but in the actual way, once both inputs are binded to the same model `[(ngModel)]="(testObject?.dynamicFields)[i]"` it's normal to see the change in the other input when update the other.

Another smell is the fact that the `names` for both inputs are the same. They should be different for each input.

I will reference the **template driven forms** official angular documentation  for more details about [Naming control elements](https://angular.io/guide/forms#naming-control-elements).

As an example, if the template is modified to use for each model a property (field), then they would not interfere each other.

```
<div *ngIf="testLabels.length > 0">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of testObject.dynamicFields; let i = index">
      <input
        *ngIf="testLabels[i]?.type === 'text'"
        [name]="'fieldOne_' + i"
        [(ngModel)]="item.fieldOne"
      >
      <kendo-datetimepicker
        class="form-control m-b-20"
        [name]="'fieldTwo_' + i"
        *ngIf="filterLabels[i]?.dataType === 'date'"
        [format]="'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'"
        [(ngModel)]="item.fieldTwo"
      ></kendo-datetimepicker>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Attention: we can use the `item` itself and not the `(testObject?.dynamicFields)[i]` because it acts like a `foreach`, where `item` represents the iterated object, not only the index as with `for`.